# Send data from component to controller

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, angular6

I have a component which has an id which I want to pass to the controller of that component. This is the class which extends the FaqController. This is the `faq.ts`

```
export class FaqPage extends FaqController {
  constructor(
    injector: Injector,
    public viewController: ViewController,
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams
  )
  {
    super(injector);
    console.log(this.navParams.get('id')) 
  }
}
```

I have a controller which handles data from a elastic search I have a method in my `service` which needs the `id` from the `faq.ts` to complete the correct query:

`faq.controller.ts`

```
data = {
    sections: null,
    search: '',
    menuFaq: [],
    results: []
}
findById() {
    this.faqService.findById(id, new RequestObject({
        onSuccess: (menuFaq) => {
            this.data.menuFaq = menuFaq;
        }
    }));
}
```

In the method `findById()` above I need the id of the `faq.ts` file how can I achieve this?

Comment: why is everyone downvoting without explaining the downvote? is this anti-pattern? is this too vague? is this with the wrong tags? The inner machinations of the mind of the average stackoverflower are an enigma...

Comment: @tatsu that was I thinking too, if they give me feedback than I can edit my question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need to separate FaqPage and FaqController, since FaqPage is already a Controller. I would suggest just call the faqService directly.

Just like this:

```
export class FaqPage {
  data = {
      sections: null,
      search: '',
      menuFaq: [],
      results: []
  }
  constructor(
    injector: Injector,
    public viewController: ViewController,
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams
  )
  {
    console.log(this.navParams.get('id')) 
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.findById(this.navParams.get('id'));
  }

  findById(id) {
    this.faqService.findById(id, new RequestObject({
        onSuccess: (menuFaq) => {
            this.data.menuFaq = menuFaq;
        }
    }));
  }
}
```

Anyway if you sure you want to do that, passing the NavParams or FAQ id inside the constructor of FaqController should be work

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you have a base class `FaqController` and you have a class that extends this class called `FaqPage`. Now you want to use a value that is established in `FaqPage` and use it in `FaqController`.

As you get the page id in the constructor, you could pass this on to your controller.

```
class FaqController {
    constructor(injector: Injector, private pageId: number) {
       // ...
    }
}
```

Now in your findById you can reference the page id with `this.pageId`.

Only thing left to do is change the constructor of `FaqPage`:

```
constructor(
    injector: Injector,
    public viewController: ViewController,
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams
)
{
    super(injector, this.navParams.get('id'));
}
```